# INNER JOIN to get Max value from one table and return the name from another table. (SQlite)

Tags: sqlite

I have created 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE locations(location STRING, id INT);

CREATE TABLE temperatures(location_id INT, temperature INT, day INT)
```

I am using `SELECT location_id, day, MAX(temperature) FROM temperatures;` to get the max Temperature out of every day from a single location(the location is mentioned in the URL by id). Is there a way that I  can get the `location` from `locations` table based on the `id`? So the result will be something like :

> `61.1435,-1.1234 | 5 |35.5`

instead of :

> `0 | 5 | 35.5`

In simple words I want to replace the location_id of the result with the actual location (coordinates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not join the two tables? Something like:

```
SELECT locations.location, temperatures.day, temperatures.temperatur FROM temepratures, locations where temperatures.location_id = locations.id
```

Or search in google for JOINS, you will find your answer.

Comment: I actually managed to get it working with the following: 
SELECT l.location, MAX(t.temperature) AS temperature FROM locations l JOIN temperatures t on t.location_id = 0(or 1 or 2) 'AND t.location_id = l.id;'
Thank you for taking time to answer :)

Comment: Perfekt, no problem. If my answer helped you to fix your problem, it will be great if you can vote it. Thank you